# Ubuntu 19.10 randomly on boot shows black screen with cursor blinking on top left

Tags: boot, 19.10

Hi randomly at times on Ubuntu 19.10 I will boot my computer up and before the login screen the display will show as a black screen with a blinking cursor on the top left.

I will have to hard reboot to get out of this where it will boot back into ubuntu and I am able to log in. When the log in screen appears, I know for certain the issue won't happen.

Is there any fix for this?

Thanks in advance :)

[black screen with cusor blinking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cfRS.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: no it doesn't, as when i hard reboot it goes through fine with no issues, it seems like it only happens on cold boots